# ScreenShot of an UILabel and what is in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of my UIImageView and a UILabel that is on top of that.

What I have so far grabs the UIImage in the ImageView and then renders the overlay on it but the positioning of the UILabel is all wrong.  I am setting the size of the capture to the actual image size(which isn't what i want).

I just want to be able to take a screenshot exactly how it appears on the screen.

```
CGSize imageSize = self.imageFromOtherView.size;
// define the size and grab a UIImage from it
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);

[self.imageFromOtherView drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];

[self.socialLabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Are you looking to get a screenshot of the entire window or just of your image on the screen?  It's a bit difficult to tell from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UIView to hold both the UIImageView and UILabel. Then pass this container view through this code. I have my view as a property called viewForPhoto so when the code is called it only captures that view. You can tweak it so that it receives a view. This will return the UIImage that you want.

```
- (UIImage *)imageByRenderingView
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.viewForPhotoView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.viewForPhotoView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add both those views to a common container view, and then call `- (BOOL)drawViewHierarchyInRect:(CGRect)rect afterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates` on the view to render it in a context.